# How to make a notification for a new mail like an email notification using laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, push-notification

I am using laravel 5. And I want to make a notification like an email, when there is a new mail, it will shows the number of mails which wasn't opened yet like in the picture below. I already my the function to count the unopened mail, but I'm confuse how to call it in my view.

[image]

> The view:

```
<li>
  <a href="{{ url ('DokumenMasuk') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Dokumen Masuk</span>
    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

> The Controller:

```
public function checkNewSurat(Request $request)
{
    $checknewsurat = SuratOpen::select('id_surat')
                                ->where('id_user', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('opened', '=', '0')
                                ->count();

    $data['content'] = $checknewsurat ;

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the code `AppServiceProvider.php` and pass all the data to the layout view.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('layouts.app', function ($view) {
            $mail = MailController::checkNewSurat();

            $view->with('mail', $mail);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public static function checkNewSurat()
{
    $checknewsurat = SuratOpen::select('id_surat')
                                ->where('id_user', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('opened', '=', '0')
                                ->count();

    return $checknewsurat;
}
```

And after this you can request the `$mail` variable in the `layouts/app.blade.php` the echo the counted open mails.

Little code preview:

```
<li>
    Mails 
    @if($mail > 0)
        <span>{{ $mail }}</span>
    @endif
</li>
```

Hope this works!

Comment: I've got an error `Class 'App\Providers\View' not found` in View::composer('layouts.app', function ($view)

Comment: Add this to your uses: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` in your `appserviceprovider.php`

Comment: I wanna echo the counted open mails in my **sidebar.blade.php** . should I put `<li>
    Mails 
    @if($mail > 0)
        <span>{{ $mail }}</span>
    @endif
</li>` inside it or in **app.blade.php**?
if I add it in my **sidebar.blade.php** `<li>
              <a href="{{ url ('Inbox') }}">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Dokumen Masuk</span>
                <span class="label label-success pull-right">{{ $mail }}</span>
              </a>
            </li>` I get an error Undefined variable: mail (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\master\resources\views\sidebar.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

Than you should change in the appserviceprovide.php the file to layouts/sidebar

Comment: `public function boot()
 {
  View::composer('includes/sidebar', function ($view) {
            $mail = SuratController::checkNewSurat();

            $view->with('mail', $mail);
        });
 }`   Class 'App\Providers\SuratController' not found

Comment: You need to add use App\SuratController

Comment: I've tried that, but then Class 'App\SuratController' not found.

Comment: Which namespace do you use?

Comment: namespace App\Providers in my AppServiceProvider. And in my SuratController the namespace is namespace App\Http\Controllers